# Pass context to store data in Room

Tags: android, kotlin, save, android-room

I am trying to save received data to local storage using Room library.
I have created a database class in which I define the parameters I need and define the context

And also I have a class in which I define the content I need for the database. But my problem is that I can't pass context. On the line
`db = NetworkDatabase.getInstance(this)` I get a `Type mismatch error: Required:Context Found:Pocket Scout Interceptor.`

Please tell me how can I fix my mistake.

```
    class PocketScoutInterceptor() : Interceptor {
    lateinit var db: NetworkDatabase
    lateinit var dao: PacketDao

    fun buildPacket(timestamp: Long, duration: Double, request: Request, response: Response, ) {

        val reqBody = request.body
        val respBody = response.body?.string()

        db = NetworkDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.packetDao()

        val packet = Packet(
            id = 0,
            userId = PocketScoutConfig.userId,
            deviceId = PocketScoutConfig.deviceId,
            sessionId = PocketScoutConfig.sessionId,
            timestamp = timestamp,
            duration = duration.roundToInt(),
            protocol = "http",
            request = room.entities.Request(
                request_method = request.method,
                request_url = request.url.toUrl().toString(),
                request_headers = request.headers.toString(),
                request_body = (reqBody?.toString() ?: ""),
                request_size = (reqBody?.toString()?.length ?: 0),
            ),
            room.entities.Response(
                response_code = response.code,
                response_headers = response.headers.toString(),
                response_body = (respBody ?: ""),
                response_size = (respBody?.length ?: 0),
            )
        )
        dao.add(packet)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code to create `db` requires `context` as a param: `NetworkDatabase.getInstance(this)`. So you can pass a context as a param to your interceptor, something like:

```
class PocketScoutInterceptor(val context: Context) : Interceptor {
    ...
    NetworkDatabase.getInstance(context)
```

Pass application context, not activity to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Спасибо, ваш совет мне помог!